# Java FileOutputStream Default Creation Path

Tags: java

Let's say I have below code:

```
String fileName = "name.txt";
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
wb.write(fileOut);
```

This way, the file will be created under bin folder of the project.

However, if I specific fileName at a whole path:

```
String fileName = "c:/temp/name.txt";
```

this file will be created at c:\temp folder.

Am Correct? And Why this happen, how FileOutputStream work?

Comment: Why don't you run it and see what happens

Comment: Close your output streams.

Comment: I suggest you read this Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

Answer (score 3):

It's not about how `FileOutputStream` works, it's about the path that the operating system assigns to a process when it starts it

This path is called [current working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). From that directory all `relative paths` are calculated. A simple file name is a relative path (to the current working directory).

If you specify an `absolute path` then this path is used to create the file.

You can read more about paths on [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you specify an absolute path, the path is relative to current working directory.

If your current working directory is a bin folder in your project, it will be created there.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify an absolute path, e.g. if you only specify the file name, then your program or the operating system somehow needs to figure out, where to find that file. For that reason a running program always has a working directory. That happens to be the folder you start it from, by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you only specify the filename, it will be created in the current working directory. If you do specify an absolute path, it will of course be created at that path.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about relative and absolute directories. Let's say that you specif path `foo/bar`. It'll create a file `bar` in `foo` directory of your working folder. The same applies for `../foo/bar` it'll create a `bar` file in `foo` directory in the folder above the working dir. However, if you type `C:\\Documents\ and\ Settings\User\Desktop\bar` (or `/home/user/Desktop/bar`), it'll create a `bar` on your desktop. For more info take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29).